# How do I change the following SVG filter so that it will get applied to a text in an HTML element?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have tried removing the

```
<!-- DILATED TEXT -->
    <text font-size="85px" dx="125" dy="130" font-weight="700" filter="url(#outline)">upgrade yourself</text>
```

`<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />` and `in="SourceAlpha"` parts in the code, so that it would apply to the element to which is referenced via CSS, but it just wipes the text out, and it doesn't produce the outline that it's supposed to.

How do I apply the OUTLINE section to the HTML element?

All SVG text effect tutorials imply that the text is inside the SVG element, but I need to apply this text stroke via the SVG filter to text in an HTML element.

```html
<svg width="900" height="200" viewBox="100 0 900 200">
    <filter id="outline">
        <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="DILATED" operator="dilate" radius="4"></feMorphology>
        
        <feFlood flood-color="#32DFEC" flood-opacity="1" result="PINK"></feFlood>
        <feComposite in="PINK" in2="DILATED" operator="in" result="OUTLINE"></feComposite>

        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="OUTLINE" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
    </filter>

    <!-- DILATED TEXT -->
    <text font-size="85px" dx="125" dy="130" font-weight="700" filter="url(#outline)">upgrade yourself</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just apply the filter to the HTML text in the same way...

```css
p {
  font-size: 85px;
  font-weight: 700;
  filter: url(#outline);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <filter id="outline">
        <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="DILATED" operator="dilate" radius="4"></feMorphology>
        
        <feFlood flood-color="#32DFEC" flood-opacity="1" result="PINK"></feFlood>
        <feComposite in="PINK" in2="DILATED" operator="in" result="OUTLINE"></feComposite>

        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="OUTLINE" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</svg>
<p>upgrade yourself</p>
```

Comment: Ah, so it works when referenced from within the document? Okay I will test and write back. I used to do external referencing, however I am changing that practice now cause it's not supported by Safari. I can confirm that external referencing this filter doesn't work in any browser. Does it work for you?

Comment: I just tested, this filter does not work in Chrome, when referenced externally. So that was the issue. Thanks for testing this.

Comment: External referencing is bad practice anyway, no support for external referencing from Safari at all.

Comment: Firefox supports external references.